# How can I return the correct value in this block in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I am getting a compiler error

```
incompatible block pointer types sending 'BOOL'
```

All I am trying to do is return the value in my completion block in the following code:

```
-(BOOL)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password{
GlobalFunctions *function = [GlobalFunctions sharedInstance];
[function registerUserWithName:name phone:number password:password completion:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSError *error) {
    return isSuccess;
}];    
}
```

I've read other similar answers but none really solves my issue directly. Is the value returned already before the block is complete?

Comment: what does nslog(isSuccess) prints?

Comment: @the_UB it has a compile error so it can not even run

Comment: Put breakpoint on `return isSuccess;` line and do `po isSuccess`

Comment: @the_UB, you can't use breakpoints if your program won't even start

Comment: I got it! @JamesWebster is right!

Answer (score 2):

> Is the value returned already before the block is complete?

In short: **Yes**! Blocks run asynchronously. The return from the block cannot be used as the return for the method.

However, that's not what's causing the compile time error. Your block doesn't have a return type:

```
^returnType(parameters)
```

but you are returning something inside the block anyway. Have a look [here](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com) for more information on block syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is async,so you cannot get return in traditional way. If you return something form block,it is the return for block, not for function.

I think it is better to pass your logic code in callback.

`typedef void(^Callback)(BOOL success);`

```
-(void)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password callBack:(Callback)callBack{
GlobalFunctions *function = [GlobalFunctions sharedInstance];
[function registerUserWithName:name phone:number password:password completion:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSError *error) {
    callBack(isSuccess);
    }];
 }
```

Then you can use it like this

```
  [self registerUserWithUser:@"" withPhone:@"" withPassword:@"" callBack:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {

    }else{

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the block as a method parameter. You can declare your method like this.

```
-(void)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password successHandler:(void (^)(BOOL isSuccess))myBlock;
```

Implementation will be somewhat like this. At the end, you can call your success handler block parameter.

```
-(void)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password successHandler:(void (^)(BOOL isSuccess))myBlock{

    /***
     ** Do your logic here **
     ** Then call the success handler block.
     ****/
    BOOL isSuccess= FALSE;
    myBlock(isSuccess);

}
```

You can call your method like this:

```
[self registerUserWithUser:@"xyz" withPhone:@"1234" withPassword:@"abcd" successHandler:^(BOOL success){
        NSLog(@"success: %d", success);
    }];
```

Hope it helps!!